# How to use Laravel whereNotIn for two fields

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I used Laravel whereNotIn for exclude some project ids, for do that first i create exclude project id array like this

$doNotDisplayThisProjectsIds = array(4, 6, 20);

and exclude this projects using this query:

```
Project::whereNotIn('prject_id', $doNotDisplayThisProjectsIds)->get();
```

Now I want to change project status too. Enable - 1, Disable - 0, so i want to filter status - 1 result set, how to do that? please help me

Answer (score 0):

I found the anwser,

```
Project::whereNotIn('prject_id', $doNotDisplayThisProjectsIds)
                                ->where('status','=' , 1)
                                ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Query Builder:

```
DB::table(..)->select(..)->whereNotIn('prject_id', $doNotDisplayThisProjectsIds)->get();
```

Eloquent:

```
SomeModel::select(..)->whereNotIn('prject_id', $doNotDisplayThisProjectsIds)->get();
```